# Link Variable to Label on another form in vb

Tags: forms, label

I have a small program for some college coursework, i have to enter data of the gender and age of a group of people then work out the male and female percent and the child and adult percent. The bit i am stuck with is i want to display my results on labels on a separate form. Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1

Dim TotalGender As Integer
Dim TotalAge As Integer
Dim MaleCount As Integer
Dim FemaleCount As Integer
Dim ChildCount As Integer
Dim AdultCount As Integer
Dim MalePercent As Single
Dim FemalePercent As Single
Dim AdultPercent As Single
Dim ChildPercent As Single

Private Sub btnSub_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSub.Click

    If cmbGender.Text = "Male" Then
        MaleCount += 1

    End If

    If cmbGender.Text = "Female" Then
        FemaleCount += 1

    End If

    If cmbAge.Text > 18 Then
        ChildCount += 1

    End If

    If cmbAge.Text <= 18 Then
        AdultCount += 1
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnResults_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnResults.Click

    Form2.Show()

    MalePercent = MaleCount / TotalGender * 100
    FemalePercent = FemaleCount / TotalGender * 100

    AdultPercent = AdultCount / TotalAge * 100
    ChildPercent = ChildCount / TotalAge * 100





End Sub

Private Sub btnReset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click


    TotalGender = 0
    TotalAge = 0
    MaleCount = 0
    FemaleCount = 0
    ChildCount = 0
    AdultCount = 0
    MalePercent = 0
    FemalePercent = 0
    AdultPercent = 0
    ChildPercent = 0
End Sub
```

End Class

My second form has all the labels already placed and i know how to display results on a label, i just don't know how to transfer the results across to another form

Comment: You can make properties on `Form2` for each field that you need to display.  You will want to set the properties before you display the form, so I would recommend moving your `Form2.Show()` to the bottom of you click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write on form 1 .It shows your results on form2

```
Form2.Label1.Text = AdultCount
        Form2.Show()
```